# jQuery: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to display or hide a span based on the selection of a checkbox. Here's my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('#chkShowDescriptions').change(function () {
        var display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
        $('.desc').css('display', display);
    }
    );
</script>

<p>
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "chkShowDescriptions" 
     name = "chkShowDescriptions" />Show Descriptions
</p>

@if(@item.Description != null)
{
    <span class = "desc" style = 
    "font-size: 0.7em; color: Gray; text-align: 
    justify; display: none;">
    Description: @item.Description<br />
    </span>
}
```

However, I get a run-time exception that says: `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected`

I am using IE 8 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the error. Or so I think.

I think I put the script tag declaration before including the jQuery library declaration/include.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know how it works.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $('#chkShowDescriptions').change(function () {
        $('.desc').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: At what line are you getting this error?